# Add line breaks to nested lists in Markdown

Tags: markdown, octopress

I am new to Markdown and stuck. As of now, I am learning to be honest with Markdown itself using the Jekryllrb platform - I use the same for my blog via Octopress; however, I am finding it difficult to add a line break after a nested sublist (unordered) to it's superlist (ordered). Here is the sample:

```
1. [Lucideus Tech](http://www.lucideus.com) - 2011 - 2012 (1 Year)
    - Security Analyst
    - R&D @Lucideus Labs
    - Web Application Penetration Tester  
2. [CTG Security Solutions](http://www.ctgsecuritysolutions.com) - 2012 (8 Months)
    - Trainer Scheduler
    - Web Application Security Trainer  
3. Defencely Cloud Security Pvt. Ltd. - 2013 to Present (2015)
    - Red Team Lead
    - Web Application Security Specialist
    - Technical Specialist and SPOC @Application Security
```

How do I add a line break after each of the ending sublists to keep them all neat, since if not, it all looks out of context and ridicules the styling?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to explain your question? Do you want vertical whitespace between, for example, "Web Application Penetration Tester" and "CTG Security Solutions"?

Comment: Yes, a vertical one on those you have mentioned ( a new paragraph). Here's the current setting of how it looks like. 

<img src="http://s23.postimg.org/uz6ujmqtn/badmarkup.png" width="100" height="100">

I would also like a solution for a new line feed, which is a new line and not an entire new paragraph (<br/>

Answer (score 24):

Adding `<br>` tags in Markdown is somewhat unintuitive because of the way it handles paragraphs. From [Paragraphs and Line Breaks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) on the syntax page:

> When you *do* want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

This answers your second question.

The first is a bit trickier, and it relates back to Markdown's design goals, as explained in the [Inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) section of that same document:

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for *writing* for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it … The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format.

Adding space between those list items is a *styling* question, not a semantic one. Markdown doesn't say anything about styling; it is entirely focused on writing, and therefore on semantics.

I believe that the best way to add your vertical space is to do it by applying CSS on the HTML output from Markdown, for example by styling `<ul>` tags contained in `<li>` tags, e.g.

```
li > ul {
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: This answers the question which means by default, there is no way I could add a space between the needed new line <li> elements after having finished with <ul> elements which are part of the sublists of it's superlist (the superlist itself being the <li>).

I was wondering to style the padding, I should change the octopress sass folder and the folders thereneath?

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick, I don't believe that there's a way to add space between these list items in Markdown. CSS is an appropriate tool (probably the best one) to use when styling HTML. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, it does. I was curious if I could alter some files at /sass/ directories on octopress installations to make this one work out.